# Interesting SQL issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a SQL problem I am trying to digest. I am using SQL Server 2005.

In a table I have data as such:

```
ID     Type
1        A
2        A
3        A
3        B
4        B
```

I need to find all of the IDs that have a Type of both A and B.

Comment: Maybe you could try formatting your table a bit better? :-)

Comment: +1 The simplest (and clearest) context to study (or explaine) all possible joins, intersects and what else?

Answer (score 12):

Use the [INTERSECT operator](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/05/02/60194.aspx):

```
   SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM [Table] WHERE Type = 'A'
   INTERSECT
   SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM [Table] WHERE Type = 'B'
```

Comment: Do we really need 'DISTINCT' here

Comment: There is no need in both DISTINCTs. The answerer does not understand INTERSECT though I upvoted him

Answer (score 11):

```
select distinct a.id 
from table a
join table b on a.id=b.id
where a.type='A'
and b.type='B';
```

Comment: Oh snap.  The distinct is going to cost you unless there is a PK/unique constraint on (id, type).

Comment: @Jeffrey Hantin: If there's a PK/Unique constraint over (id,type) then you don't need to use the `DISTINCT` query modifier.

Comment: This is ugly solution. Besides using "WHERE" with join is anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

With a semi-join (no sorting, only index seek on B):

```
select a.id from table a
    where a.type = 'A'
      and exists (select * from table b where a.id = b.id and b.type = 'B')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to abstract the problem a little bit and find cases where rows with the same id contain different values in the type column, you can check for <> like this:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (thisid int, thisval varchar(1))

INSERT INTO @TestTable VALUES  (1, 'A')
INSERT INTO @TestTable VALUES  (2, 'A')
INSERT INTO @TestTable VALUES  (3, 'A')
INSERT INTO @TestTable VALUES  (3, 'B')
INSERT INTO @TestTable VALUES  (4, 'B')

SELECT DISTINCT thisid
FROM @TestTable a
WHERE EXISTS
( SELECT * 
FROM @TestTable b
WHERE a.thisid=b.thisid AND a.thisval<>b.thisval)
-- www.caliberwebgroup.com
```

This returns:

```
3
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for complete reproducible (ready to run) sript! though you should have used id (but not thisid) and type (but thisval)!

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, count(type = 'A') as a_count, count(type = 'B') as b_count
from your_table
group by 1
having a_count > 0 and b_count > 0;
```

At least, this works in sane SQL environments.  Dunno if it works in yours.

Comment: Neither "count(type = 'A')" nor "group by 1" works in SQL Server! Can you, at least, name sane SQL and RDBMS?

Comment: Yup.  PostgreSQL, freely available on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I was not looking at other answers, but still posting. lol

```
SELECT distinct t1.ID
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE exists 
   (select t2.ID from table1 t2 where t2.type="A" and t2.ID=t1.ID) 
   and exists 
   (select t3.ID from table1 t3 where t3.type="B" and t3.ID=t1.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Id FROM tableX AS x, tableX AS y
WHERE x.id = y.id AND x.type = 'A' AND y.type = 'B'

Comment: This query gives error "Ambiguous column name 'Id'". One should SELECT x.ID (instead of SELCT Id). Besides, it probably needs DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple

```
Declare @t table([ID] INT, [Type] VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 1, 'A' UNION ALL SELECT 2,'A' UNION ALL SELECT 3,'A' 
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'B' UNION ALL SELECT 4,'B' UNION ALL SELECT 5,'A' UNION ALL SELECT 5,'A'

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Rn = Row_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ID],[TYPE] ORDER BY [ID])
    ,*
    FROM @t
)
SELECT ID 
FROM CTE 
WHERE Rn =1 AND ([Type]='A' or [Type]='B')
GROUP BY [ID]
HAVING (COUNT([ID])>1)
```

**Output:**

**id**

```
3
```

Comment: +1 for the simplicity of the solution. Mine is on similar lines but very complex.

Comment: This doesn't work if the values can be repeated, i.e. if ID 1 has two rows with 'A'.  If there is a unique constraint on (ID, Type) it would, as long as 'A' and 'B' are the only possible types.

Comment: I agree with @Jason Goemaat. If to add 2+ rows (5, A), i.e. without any type 'B" for id=5, this query will output 5 also!

Answer (score -1):

this would help if there are "unknown" amounts of types and you want to find all IDs which have all of types

```
select id from yourtable group by id having count(*)=(select  count(distinct type) from yourtable)
```

Comment: This gives completely incorrect results missing correct ones and outputting wrong (if you extend a little bit original table). Just add the row with id=2 and Type='B' and the result of your query will be 2 (missing 3 and the following correct ids, if to add them)

Answer (score -1):

```
select id
from idtypedata
group by id
having 
sum(
    case type
        when 'A' then 1
        when 'B' then 2
        -- when 'C' then 4
        -- when 'D' then 8
    end
    ) & 1 = 1
And 
sum(
    case type
        when 'A' then 1
        when 'B' then 2
        -- when 'C' then 4
        -- when 'D' then 8
    end
    ) & 2 = 2
```

Comment: You are the winner of contest of the most ugly, overcomplicated and incorrect solution. Just add the row with id=2 and Type='B' andthe result of your query will be 2 (missing 3)